# PHP unitialized string offset: 0

Tags: php

I decided to give PHP a try, and then bought lynda.com's essential training tutorial.
The problem is, that I get this error:

> ( ! ) Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in
>   C:\wamp\www\widget_corp\includes\functions.php on line 147.

when trying to compare two values.

Can anyone help me ? :)

error in navigation function:

```
if($page["id"] == $selectedPage['id']){
```

**Class content.php below:**

```
<?php require_once("includes/connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/functions.php");?>
<?php findSelectedPage(); ?>
<?php include("includes/header.php");?>

<table id="structure">
      <tr>
        <td id="navigation">
            <?php echo navigation($selSubject, $selectedPage);?>
            <br/>
            <a href="new_subject.php">+ Add a new subject</a>
        </td>
        <td id="page">
            <?php echo checkSubjOrPage();?>
            <br/>
            <div id="footer">Copyright 2007, Widget Corp</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
<?php require("includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

**class function.php below:**

```
<?php
    //This file is the place to store all basic functions.

    //NB!
    //function to prevent problems with submitting values, that contains
    //chars such as: "", '' etc., into the database.
    function mysql_prep($value){
        $magic_quotes_active = get_magic_quotes_gpc;

        //i.e. php>= v4.3.0
        $new_enough_php = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string");

        if($new_enough_php){
            //undo any magic quotes effects so mysql_real_escape_string can do the work
            if($magic_quotes_active){
                $value = stripslashes($value);
            }
            $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
        } else { // before PHP v4.3.0
            //if magic quotes aren't already on then add slashed manually
            if(!$magic_quotes_active){
                $value = addslashes($value);
            }
        }

        return $value;
    }

    function confirm_query($result_set){
        if(!$result_set){
            die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
        }
    }

    function getAllSubjects(){
        global $connection;
        $query = "SELECT *
                    FROM subjects
                    ORDER BY position ASC";

        $subject_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
        confirm_query($subject_set);

        return $subject_set;
    }

    function getPagesForSubject($subject_id){
        global $connection;
        $query = "SELECT *
                    FROM pages
                    WHERE subject_id = {$subject_id}
                    ORDER BY position ASC";

        $page_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
        confirm_query($page_set);

        return $page_set;
    }

    function get_subject_by_id($subject_id){
        global $connection;
        $query = "SELECT * ";
        $query .= "FROM subjects ";
        $query .= "WHERE id=" . $subject_id . " ";
        $query .= "LIMIT 1";

        $result_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
        confirm_query($result_set);

        //REMEMBER: 
        //if no rows are returned, fetch_array will return false.
        if($subject = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)){
            return $subject;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    function get_page_by_id($page_id){
        global $connection;
        $query = "SELECT * ";
        $query .= "FROM pages ";
        $query .= "WHERE id=" . $page_id . " ";
        $query .= "LIMIT 1";

        $result_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
        confirm_query($result_set);

        //REMEMBER: 
        //if no rows are returned, fetch_array will return false.
        if($page = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)){
            return $page;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    function checkSubjOrPage(){
        global $selSubject;
        global $selectedPage;

        if(!is_null($selSubject)){
            return "<h2>" . $selSubject['menu_name'] . "</h2>";
        } else if(!is_null($selectedPage)){
            return "<h2>" . $selectedPage['menu_name'] . "</h2>" . "<div>" . $selectedPage['content'] . "</div>";
        } else {
            return "<h2>" . "Select a subject or page to edit!" . "</h2>";
        }
    }

    function findSelectedPage(){
        global $selSubject;
        global $selectedPage;

        if(isset($_GET['subj'])){
            $selSubject = get_subject_by_id($_GET['subj']);
            $selectedPage = "";
        } else if(isset($_GET['page'])){
            $selSubject = NULL;
            $selectedPage = get_page_by_id($_GET['page']);
        } else {
            $selectedPage = NULL;
            $selSubject = NULL;
        }
    }

    function navigation($selSubject, $selectedPage){
        $output =  "<ul class=\"subjects\">";
        //3. Perform our database query
        $subject_set = getAllSubjects();

        while($subject = mysql_fetch_array($subject_set)){
            $output .= "<li";
            if($subject["id"] == $selSubject['id']){
                $output .= " class=\"selected\"";
            }  
                $output .= "><a href=\"content.php?subj=" . urlencode($subject["id"]) .
                "\">{$subject["menu_name"]}</a></li>";

                $page_set = getPagesForSubject($subject["id"]);

                $output .= "<ul class=\"pages\">";   
                while($page = mysql_fetch_array($page_set)){
                    $output .= "<li";
                    if($page["id"] == $selectedPage['id']){
                        $output .= " class=\"selected\"";
                }
                    $output .= "><a href=\"content.php?page=" . urlencode($page{"id"}) .
                    "\">{$page["menu_name"]}</a></li>";
                }
                $output .= "</ul>";
            }

                $output .= "</ul>";

                return $output;
    }
    function getPositions(){
        $subject_set = getAllSubjects();
        $subject_counts = mysql_num_rows($subject_set);
        $output = "<select name=\"position\">";

        //$subject_counts + 1 b/c we are adding a subject.
        for($count = 1; $count <= $subject_counts +1; $count++){
            $output .= "<option value=\"{$count}\">{$count}</option>";
        }

        return $output . " </select>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: if i can provide additional information, that might help you help me, pls let me know :)

Comment: and pls be gentle, i am new to PHP :p

Comment: Before that line, add `var_dump($page, $selectedPage);` to make sure they are both arrays, and have the keys you want.

Comment: That seems that you redeclared one of the variables `$page` or `$selectedPage` to string...

Comment: We would need to see the code that calls the function `navigation()`. Looks like you are passing a string to the `$selectedPage` parameter instead of an array.

Comment: okay, hang on just a sec, i will post it

Comment: i think, that maybe somewhere i redeclare $page or $selectedPage to a string maybe.. But i can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you override $selectedPage  to a string or set it to *null*

```
function findSelectedPage(){
        global $selSubject;
        global $selectedPage;

        if(isset($_GET['subj'])){
            $selSubject = get_subject_by_id($_GET['subj']);
            $selectedPage = "";
        } else if(isset($_GET['page'])){
            $selSubject = NULL;
            $selectedPage = get_page_by_id($_GET['page']);
        } else {
            $selectedPage = NULL;
            $selSubject = NULL;
        }
    }
```

And here it should be an array:

```
if($page["id"] == $selectedPage['id']){
```

---

```
function findSelectedPage(){
    global $selSubject;
    global $selectedPage;

    if(isset($_GET['subj'])){
        $selSubject = get_subject_by_id($_GET['subj']);
        $selectedPage = NULL;
    } else if(isset($_GET['page'])){
        $selSubject = NULL;
        $selectedPage = get_page_by_id($_GET['page']);
    } else {
        $selectedPage = NULL;
        $selSubject = NULL;
    }
}

function navigation($selSubject, $selectedPage){
    $output =  "<ul class=\"subjects\">";
    //3. Perform our database query
    $subject_set = getAllSubjects();

    while($subject = mysql_fetch_array($subject_set)){
        $output .= "<li";
        if(isset($selSubject['id']) && $subject["id"] == $selSubject['id']){
            $output .= " class=\"selected\"";
        }  
        $output .= "><a href=\"content.php?subj=" . urlencode($subject["id"]) .
        "\">{$subject["menu_name"]}</a></li>";

        $page_set = getPagesForSubject($subject["id"]);

        $output .= "<ul class=\"pages\">";   
        while($page = mysql_fetch_array($page_set)){
            $output .= "<li";
            if(isset($selectedPage['id']) && $page["id"] == $selectedPage['id']){
                $output .= " class=\"selected\"";
        }
            $output .= "><a href=\"content.php?page=" . urlencode($page{"id"}) .
            "\">{$page["menu_name"]}</a></li>";
        }
        $output .= "</ul>";
    }

    $output .= "</ul>";

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: okay thank you very much, kind sir! 

Well, im new to php, so can someone please help me reach a solution?

Comment: first i like to mention that the two function **getPagesForSubject** and **getAllSubjects** return a result_set and no array .. this may be an error

Comment: I discovered that if i just say if($page["id"] == $selectedPage) instead, then it actually works, but then my css does not apply. Which means that it jumps over the if-else statement. What can i do about that?

Comment: the problem seems to be $selectedPage

Comment: yeah I added a function that retrieve the selectedPage from the subject_id .. I hope that fixes the problem .. please change your last editing back to original version.

Comment: I know i already set the answer, but i do have one more problem after i added your methods. It kinda works, but, i have a problem with it applying the css (i.e. making it bold) to more list items at the same time.

Comment: have you tried my version with **if($page["id"] == $selectedPage[id])**  That maybe solve the css error

Comment: I implemented you version of function findSelectedPage instead of my original one. And then i added the function findSelectedPage() to my function.php file too

Comment: Do u want me to make a new question, with the new implementations?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6904/discussion-between-rauschen-and-thomas-teilmann)